# Woocommerce Shop: Domain hosting on X (namecheap), WP hosting on Y (siteground) = Loading Time Issues?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dns, hosting

Is my woocommerce shop facing loading time issues when I host the domain with namecheap (for example) and use another company like siteground (e.g.) for hosting the WordPress site?

I'm wondering if it's better to host both things (domain and WP installation) with one company (for example siteground).

Goal: the faster the shop page is loading the better:)

Help is very much appreciated. I don't have much experience with this yet.

Comment: personally having domain and hosting with same company hasn't made vast differences in load speed, so many factors can cause slow loads speeds its a case of debugging everything, personally found hosting in a droplet like digital ocean or use a managed service like cloudways gave us better results.
 
in terms of speed you need to look at your themes your plugins and and your images running page speed tests on gtmetrix and google page speed will give you list of a fixes to concentrate on but your question is super broad

Comment: but how is it, that I get a bad rating at "DNS lookup" when I do a page speed load test with pingdom... the explanation reads. "The Domain Name System (DNS) maps hostnames to IP addresses, just like phonebooks map people's names to their phone numbers. When you type URL www.yahoo.com into the browser, the browser contacts a DNS resolver that returns the server's IP address. DNS has a cost; typically it takes 20 to 120 milliseconds for it to look up the IP address for a hostname. The browser cannot download anything from the host until the lookup completes" so two companies do matter!?

Comment: your dns look up score is not coming from your domain its coming from amount of dns look up requests its making 

if your site is running alot scripts you will be getting bad dns look up score https://kinsta.com/blog/reduce-dns-lookups/

Answer (score 1):

Having a domain and hosting with different companies **does not affect** the speed of your website at all.

The load speed is fully dependent on the host server capacity and how well your website is coded. Well, Wordpress sites without optiization are pretty massive.

I suggest checking what can be optimized within your website to make it more "light'. I've used this tool https://gtmetrix.com/, you can also check any other similar tool like Google Speed test, etc.